# Joomla 2.5 remove text under header logo beez5 template?

Tags: joomla2.5

i'm devloping a sitehttp://examplesofandroid.com/  in joomla having template beez5.
i want to remove the text "Open Source Content Management" from the page. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by going to template `beez5` and open the `index.php` and search for the given code:

```
<span class="header1">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($templateparams->get('sitedescription'));?>
</span>
```

Just comment out this and you done.

Answer (score 0):

-go to Extensions > Template Manager 
-and choose your template Beez5-Default and click upon it.
-you will reach the page Template Manager: Edit Style.
-in that page you can change or remove "Open Source Content Management" from the page in Site Description text box.